# How to change plot legends with roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I'm plotting ROC curve with `plot_roc_curve` of `scikit-learn`, that plot legends are printed automatically. Is there a way to change them?

```
metrics.plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much add anything you like to the plot object that is produced through `plot_roc_curve`. For instance, you can do something like this:

```
plot_roc_curve(classifier, X_test, y_test, ax=plt.gca(), label="Legend")
plt.xlabel("Your x label text")
plt.ylabel("Your y label text")
plt.title("Some title")
```

This will return:

[image: ROC curve]

Comment: Thank you. Can I edit part of automatic generated legends and keep the score? For example convert `LogisticRegression (AUC = 0.82)` to `LR (AUC = 0.82)`.

Comment: @Flodude try `name='LR'`.